# How to dynamically load and append new data to the same exapanded collapsible div section on scroll down event

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-mobile

using jquery mobile collapsible set(accordian) div,i have loaded multiple sections with data.On expanding a collapsible section div, i need to show only first 20 data from server side. While scrolling down and on reaching the end of 20 th data of expanded collapsible div section,i need load to next 20 data from server side and append it at the end of same expanded collapsible section.

What event or listener to be used to detect cursor  scroll down event has reached the end of expanded collapsible div section?
And How to dynamically load and append new data to the same exapanded collapsible div section on scroll down event (like facebook load data?)

Answer (score 0):

$().scroll(function...) is your solution. Your fonction will be called each time the user scroll.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply.

I checked using $(window).scroll(function),but it is not working iOS mobile devices.

How to fire an event on scroll in mobile web page.

Comment: Sorry I haven't see it was for iOS. I don't know the answer.